# Did the Dominion of Newfoundland establish diplomatic missions?

Tags: diplomacy

Before 1949 Newfoundland was a separate country from Canada and both Newfoundland and Canada were "dominions". In Canada the status of a "dominion" meant that it was an independent country except that its constitution could be amended only by the British Parliament, and in particular it sent and received ambassadors. Did Newfoundland also send and receive ambassadors?

Comment: Dominion actually meant self-government ("responsible government") originally, not that it was an "independent country", although all dominions gradually became that. So none of the Dominions were permitted to conduct independent foreign affairs, including establishing embassies, until the 1930s. Newfoundland, whose Dominion status was suspended when it gave up self-rule, missed the boat (I personally wouldn't consider internal British Empire representation diplomatic missions in this period).

Comment: @Semaphore : So does that mean Canada did not have embassies until the 1930s?

Comment: Well... it's complicated. Canada's first diplomatic mission was to Washington D.C., in 1927, but that was technically only a Legation (headed by an Envoy). The first Ambassador was officially appointed only in 1943, at which point the legation became an Embassy.

Comment: @Semaphore: That would be by the [*Statute of Westminster*](http://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/statute-of-westminster/) ([as also here re Australia](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/when-did-australia-declare-war-on-germany-in-wwii/11529)) I presume.

Comment: @Semaphore : Perhaps you should post an answer. And maybe it can clarify how it is that if "none of the Dominions were permitted to conduct independent foreign affairs, including establishing embassies, until the 1930s" then it is also the case that the Canadians established a legation in Washington in the '20s.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Seriously? A legation is explicitly not an embassy and Canada secured permission to establish direct contact; doesn't mean foreign policy wasn't still controlled by Britain. Read up on the law Pieter Geerkens linked.

Comment: @Semaphore : From where I'm sitting the difference between a legation and an embassy is that one is called a legation and the other is called an embassy, and the diplomat is called an envoy or a minister rather than an ambassador. And you didn't mention earlier that they had been given permission. That seems essential.

Comment: I guess I deserved that for trying to answer your question as literally written instead of presuming ignorance. As for permission, I thought that was implied from my preceding statement that they didn't have independent control until the 1930s. Obviously, I did not anticipate adversarial attempts at poking "holes" in quick comments intended only to share knowledge, or I'd have been more careful securing my words with qualifications.

Comment: @Semaphore : I haven't attempted to be adversarial at all. I didn't understand how it could be said that it wasn't allowed and yet it was done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Dominion of Newfoundland sent High Commissioners to the United Kingdom from 1918 to 1934 when the Dominion was abolished[1]. It is of note that, unlike other Dominions of the United Kingdom including Canada, the United Kingdom did not send a High Commissioner to the Dominion of Newfoundland.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_commissioner_of_Newfoundland_to_the_United_Kingdom